# R/Lme4: Trouble specifying random effects properly in a repeated measures logistic HLM

Tags: r, logistic, multilevel-analysis, lme4-nlme

I am having trouble getting appropriate random effects output when using the `glmer` command in `lme4`.

My dataset is a long-form repeated measures observation for 45 subjects. I have some between-subjects factors that I am using to model whether the participants are correct or incorrect on a given trial. I want to include these variables as both random and fixed effects.

```
Model <- glmer(Correct ~ Block + Intensity + Emotion + (1|Subject) 
+ (1 + Block | Subject) + (1 + Intensity|Subject) 
+ (1 + Emotion|Subject) data = data, family = binomial("logit"))
```

Is this the correct way to specify random effects for these variables? It seems to be based on my understanding of how `glmer` works but using this code returns the following as a random effects output:

```
Random effects:
Groups    Name         Variance  Std.Dev. Corr 

Subject   (Intercept)  6.830e-01 0.826440      

Subject.1 (Intercept)  3.913e-01 0.625541      
          Block        1.680e-05 0.004099 -0.99

Subject.2 (Intercept)  3.780e-01 0.614842      
          Intensity    1.605e-04 0.012670 -1.00

Subject.3 (Intercept)  3.902e-01 0.624695      
          Emotion      3.324e+00 1.823087 -0.22
```

This doesn't seem to be an appropriate input for interpreting the random effect of these varaibles. Am I misunderstanding this output or is there a better way to specify this model?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: @Tavrock Does not seem like self-study to me, and typically the OP should be requested to add the tag if it applies.

Comment: Looks OK to me. The output matches what you specified. However, I cannot comment on whether what you specified is reasonable or not since I cannot find a [reproducible example](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Reproducibility.html). The grouping factor is `Subject` and should be indicated with 45 groups in the output (the part that you did not provide). Then you allow for 3 random slopes (`Block`, `Intensity`, `Emotion`) in your grouping factor `Subject` indicated as `Subject.1`,`Subject.2` and `Subject.3`.